# QML ListView - Limit the number of items displayed in the list

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qt-quick

I have a `ListView` `ListModel` with 10 ListElements, I want the ListView to display the first ListElement from the model.

Is there a way to limit the number of `ListElement` items that are displayed, or select the `ListElement` to display from an ID in the data?

Example ListModel:

```
ListModel {
    id: homeMenuModelData
    ListElement {
        name: "Sam Wise Is A Very Wise Man"
        number: "555 0473"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "Bill Smith"
        number: "555 3264"
    }
    ListElement {
        name: "John Brown"
        number: "555 8426"
    }
}
```

The ListView:

```
ListView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    interactive: false
    model: HomeMenuModel
    delegate: homeMenuDelegate
    highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5 }
    focus: true
}
```

I'm thinking something like this would be useful to me:

```
model.clear();
for( var i=0; i < bookList.length ; ++i ) {
    model.append(bookList[i]);
}
```

****** Updated ******

Props to @folibis (below comments) for the suggestion, good explanation here of using `DelegateModel` and `filterOnGroup`: [Is it possible to show only certain indexes of a QML listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941043/is-it-possible-to-show-only-certain-indexes-of-a-qml-listview)

Comment: That doesn't look like QML @ANDYMURAY

Comment: You should apply a filter to your model in order to list only the elements you need. Take a look here : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html

Comment: Sorry CLiown ,i thought it's from Android .

Comment: But i got this link for pagination : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21960031/how-to-implement-pagination-in-a-qt-5-2-qml-app

Comment: Maybe you want `DelegateModel` with `filterOnGroup` set

Comment: Why in your listView the model is `model: HomeMenuModel` .. I thought it should be `model:homeMenuModelData`

Comment: HomeMenuModel is being loaded from a seperate file, I'm using files to store some fixture data. So doing import "../data", where "../data" contains a qmldir file that points to my ListModel with ListElements. @MohammadKanan

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to show only certain indexes of a QML listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28941043/is-it-possible-to-show-only-certain-indexes-of-a-qml-listview)